# How to get unique value of iOS device

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, udid

I'm writing an application that is used to manage the coming time of an employer by worklight.
This app is used when the employer comes to the company every day. When they need to check in, the app will get:

```
+ geolocation
+ employer id
+ unique value of device (unchange value of device, ex: imei on Android).
```

and send the data to a database.

My problem is that I do not know which unique value of an iOS device I can take. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can no longer get a unique ID per device. identifierForVendor is the best you're going to get. Apple has systematically disabled identifying a specific device so that users' IDs can't be passed around by marketers.

UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

NSString  *currentDeviceId = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];

Comment: is "identifierForVendor" change every time user reinstall the app ?

Comment: "The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes."

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: Another option is to use `advertisingIdentifier`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingIdentifier.